# Can't find clogin command for rancid

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I'm new to CentOS and setting up Rancid (only used rancid, but new set it up).  I've having an issue were I type `clogin` as my rancid user, however i get `command not found`

```
[rancid@rancid.corpservices.iseek.com.au:/]$ clogin
bash: clogin: command not found
```

I get the same message as root user.

Can I get assistance in sorting this out?

The file is there, however it's not a executable

```
[root@rancid.corpservices.iseek.com.au:/usr/libexec/rancid]# ls | grep clogin
clogin
```

how do I enable it so I can utilise it?

Answer (score 2):

Error `command not found` is caused your shell cannot find `clogin` in directory specified on your `$PATH`. You can run `clogin` with specify full path

```
# /usr/libexec/rancid/clogin
```

Alternatively, you can add /usr/libexec/rancid/ to your PATH

```
# PATH=$PATH:/usr/libexec/rancid
# export PATH
```

**UPDATE**

To get permanent effect, put this line in your `~/.profile`

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/libexec/rancid
```